# Selenium handling popups

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation

[image: strong text]

I am trying automating my online classes using selenium. But I'm stuck when this windows popup because I cannot inspect this item.

I want to program to click on "Open zoom meetings"

Answer (score 0):

This is a windows component
Selenium cannot manage it
At times we get stuck with these kinds of authentications
You can use Robot or Auto IT to manage these windows components
You will have to integrate Robot/Auto IT scripts with Selenium code and get over this

Answer (score 0):

This question can be expressed in another way:

> How to handle windows/Alerts popups using Selenium Webdriver

This [url](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html) should help you.

Comment: Selenium is not even recognizing this as an popup/alert. So this method is not working.